# Fork - How does both the parent and child run even though it's an if else

Tags: c, unix, fork

Question A:

Given the code below, I understand that when you call a fork, most if its resources are passed  over to the child process. Now just about every Fork example I have looked up is set up like the one I have. From the looks of it, I don't understand how the parent process is ever called since it's in the else block.

Question B:

After the code in the child proces is executed, does it automatically know that it has to enter the parent process now? I have seen a wait(NULL) in other examples as well, what is the role of that wait if it is going to be entering the else block anyways. Suppose I want to execute two child processess of the same parent, would these two be running in parallel, and then running the code of the parent once it is done? Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h> 

int main()
{
        pid_t pid;
        pid = fork();

        if(pid == 0){
                printf("Hello World");
        }
        else{
                printf("Hello World");
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: The lesson to be learned: fork() is called once, but it returns twice. Parent and child are different processes.

Comment: Do you realise that fork results in **two** processes that are executing in parallel?  One which is the parent, one which is the child.

Comment: What do you mean returns twice? I am having a hard time visualizing how this works

Comment: Oli Charlesworth, I realize that but don't understand it since I can't visualize the process.

Comment: After the fork there are 2 identical copies of the parent process, only distinguished by the return value of fork

Comment: How would it know that it now the turn of the parent

Comment: "how the parent process is ever card": I can't parse this. What is "card"?

Comment: @Celada If you can't parse it, it's probably an undeclared identifier.

Comment: @user2098078: To your last question: The operating system (more precisely, the scheduler) takes care of that. Just assume that both processes continue to run *in parallel*, and the only thing that distinguishes them is the return value of `fork()`.

Comment: If I have hello world in a child process and hello world in the parent, upon it running shouldn't it print it twice?

Comment: @user2098078: Yes, it should. What do you see? On what platform do you run the example?

Comment: Ubuntu, it works now. Once my child process is done doing what it's doing, can I close it? Or does it close automatically? Suppose later down the program I fork again, how does that affect anything? An example would help me visualize things better.

Comment: @user2098078: Ok. Yes. Yes. Depends. (In order of appearance.) Please ask a separate question, with a specific example, to get more detail :-) You also might want to look into the Unix/Linux process model.

Comment: BTW: maybe you should add a \n to the format strings of the printf() -statements.

Comment: If I have a printf statement for a execvp, why does that printf statement not run?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You misunderstood the concept a bit I think. fork() clones the process, meaning the parent and the child are both executed and they both have the same if-else in their code (since they run the same code from the `fork()` down).

The child's process ID is 0 so it will enter the if, the parents process ID is not 0 so it will enter the else. This is a way to let the processes each do their own thing, even though they have the same code.

Comment: I have a printf in the child, and it prints, then I have a printf in the parent, but that does not run.

Comment: Where exactly is the `printf` statement?

Comment: I think that should work, maybe you overlooked it printing it twice on the same line? You should see `Hello WorldHello World` since you didn't use `\n`

Comment: Once my child process is done doing what it's doing, can I close it? Or does it close automatically? Suppose later down the program I fork again, how does that affect anything? An example would help me visualize things better.

Comment: If I have a printf statement for a execvp, why does that printf statement run?\

Comment: It closes automatically once it's done with all the rest of the code. As for the other fork call, it's better to read some documentation on `fork()`. This is an excellent example http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/ForkExecProcesses.html